# American English Phonetics. Silent H in What's his name?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, american-accent, word-stress, silent-letter

Is the letter 'h' silent when Americans pronounce the question 'What's his name?' in casual speech?
The question 'What's his name?' phonetically looks like: [wʌts_ɪz neɪm].

I think the words "WHAT'S" and "IZ" can be linked together because of the consonant + vowel. Am I right? Which words should I stress when I pronounce the question? "What" and "name"?

Any suggestion appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking about this question in general? I.e. when you want to know the name of a male? Or are you referring to the phrase "Whatshisname?", used when you can't remember the name of a particular individual? In the latter case, I think the "h" will almost be dropped.

Comment: In "casual speech" (and "normal, formal" speech, for an increasingly large number of speakers) the aspirated "h" in such words is less and less common.

Comment: If I were trying to speak clearly, I would definitely pronounce the h, but in normal speech, not at all;  your phonetics look accurate.  This is in contrast to a word like honor, in which I would never pronounce the h.  Basically, I realize that it should be voiced, but I don't do it out of habit.

Comment: Then there's the nickname "Herb", where the *h* is pronounced, and vegetable "herb", where it is silent.

Comment: Except that the "h" in the vegetative "herb" is pronounced in British English, IIUC.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The queen regularly doesn't pronounce the /h/ in 'him' or 'his'!

Comment: @Araucaria: She's just got the 'ump because we pinched her English and rebranded it as [Received Pronunciation!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation) :) But at least you never hear Prince Phillip refer to Her Maj as **'er indoors**.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions simply:

1. the h can be silent, and generally is in casual English when pronouncing words that begin with wh- such as what, where and whip.
2. In casual conversation, the h of *his* can become very subtle, but full omission of the h pushes this from proper English to regional dialect. When I say, "What's his name?" the h is subtle and flowing from the word preceding it, but omitting it entirely forces a glottal stop such as that heard in Cockney h-dropping, which would pronounce the same sentence as "Wots 'iz nayhm?"
3. For pronunciation of the words in casual English, the stress will be on the vowel: the /aht/ or /uht/ of what, the /hih/ of his, and the /ay/ of name.